# Footer and external text file usage for phpword

Tags: php, phpword

More questions on PhpWord class file, examples are not working for me.  I am newly trying to use this and having difficulty even with the samples given.  In this case, I am trying to include a footer on my pages with the page numbers, and then also trying to pull in the content of an external file to display in the document.

test.txt file just contains only this line of text:

> This is a test textfile to include in the phpword generated document.

Neither show up on the page.  Here is my code:

```
<?php
//testing the phpword functionality to get it to output and format correctly

require_once 'includes/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/bootstrap.php';

// Creating the new document...
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

/* Note: any element you append to a document must reside inside of a Section. */

// Adding an empty Section to the document...
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
// Adding Text element to the Section having font styled by default...
$section->addText(
    '"Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. '
    . 'The important thing is not to stop questioning." '
    . '(Albert Einstein)'
);

/*
 * Note: it's possible to customize font style of the Text element you add in three ways:
 * - inline;
 * - using named font style (new font style object will be implicitly created);
 * - using explicitly created font style object.
 */

// Adding Text element with font customized inline...
$section->addText(
    '"Great achievement is usually born of great sacrifice, '
    . 'and is never the result of selfishness." '
    . '(Napoleon Hill)',
    array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => 10)
);

// Adding Text element with font customized using named font style...
$fontStyleName = 'oneUserDefinedStyle';
$phpWord->addFontStyle(
    $fontStyleName,
    array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => 10, 'color' => '1B2232', 'bold' => true)
);
$section->addText(
    '"The greatest accomplishment is not in never falling, '
    . 'but in rising again after you fall." '
    . '(Vince Lombardi)',
    $fontStyleName
);

// Adding Text element with font customized using explicitly created font style object...
$fontStyle = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font();
$fontStyle->setBold(true);
$fontStyle->setName('Tahoma');
$fontStyle->setSize(13);
$myTextElement = $section->addText('"Believe you can and you\'re halfway there." (Theodor Roosevelt)');
$myTextElement->setFontStyle($fontStyle);

$footer = $section->addFooter();
$footer->addPreserveText('Page {PAGE} of {NUMPAGES}.', null, array('alignment' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc::CENTER));
$section->addPageBreak();

//get an external text file to display
$filename = "test.txt";
$textfile = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($filename);
$section->addText($textfile);

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'RTF');
$objWriter->save('testdoc.rtf');

?>
```

Thanks.  I'd really like to get this working or find another open source solution that works better.

Comment: why are you trying to read you test.txt file with IOFactory::load()?

Comment: Saving to RTF will not work, footnotes have only been implemented for Word2007 (docx)

Comment: IOFactory::load() -- I cannot find documentation on how to do what I'm trying to do anywhere else so that is what I was trying to do.  I'd be happy to do it anyway it actually works.   RTF -- I get errors with XMLWriter when I attempt to use the Word2007, but I'd prefer to use that.  At this point I was using RTF because I could actually get output and go from there.

Comment: instead of `\PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load` just use `file_get_contents()` to load the text

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
//get an external text file to display
$filename = "test.txt";
$textfile = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($filename);
$section->addText($textfile);
```

try

```
//get an external text file to display
$filename = "test.txt";
$textfile = file_get_contents($filename);
$section->addText($textfile);
```